# $X\cos\beta+Y\sin\beta\sim N(0,1)$, show $X$ and $Y$ are independent $N(0,1)$ random variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

**Question** Let $(X,Y)$ be a random point drawn from a two-dimensional distribution. Suppose that $X\cosβ+Y\sinβ\sim N(0,1)$ for any $β∈ \mathbb{R}$. Show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent $N(0,1)$ random variables.

---

**Attempt to Solution** Let $Z=X\cosβ+Y\sinβ\sim N(0,1)$, so using mgf,

\begin{align}
M_Z(t) & = \exp(1/2(x^2\cos^2\beta+Y^2\sin^2\beta)) \\[8pt]
& = \exp\left(\frac{x^2\cos^2\beta}{2}\right) \exp \left( \frac{y^2 \sin^2 \beta}{2}\right) \\[8pt]
&=M_X(s)M_Y(t), \\[8pt]
\text{and } X & \sim N(0,\cos^2\beta), \quad Y\sim N(0,\sin^2\beta).
\end{align}

**My confusion**

1. Is my method correct?
2. Can I conclude $X\sim N(0,1), Y\sim N(0,1)$,
   since $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: How about simply considering what happens for $\beta=0$ and for $\beta=\frac{\pi}2$?

Comment: @dfnu I get what you mean, but I feel special cases like $0,\frac{\pi}{2}$ may not be strict since $\beta$ may vary.

Comment: In this way you guarantee that $X$ and $Y$ are "special cases" of $Z$, therefore they have the same distribution. Then as in the answer below, show incorrelation (wich is equivalent to independence, for gaussian r.v.. Why?)

Comment: @christ your method is not correct since $M_z(t)$ is a function of $t$ and not of $x$ and $y$. Second, if (in some way) you arrive at $X\sim N(0,\cos^2\beta), Y\sim N(0,\sin^2\beta).$, you can not say that $X\sim N(0,1), Y\sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: @dfnu I see. First find X and Y's distribution and second prove they are independent. However, I still cannot figure out why we can use covariance to determine the independence.

Comment: @AhmadBazzi Oh, thank you! It should be $M_{XY}(s,t)=M_X(s)M_Y(t)$!

Comment: So you assumed independence when the question asks you to prove it ? @christ

Comment: Also this $M_Z(t)=exp(1/2(x^2\cos^2\beta+Y^2\sin^2\beta))$ is wrong however this $M_Z(t)=exp(-1/2(t^2))$ is correct

Comment: @AhmadBazzi No, I misused the property that $Z=X+Y, X,Y\text{ are independent.}\Rightarrow M_Z(t)=M_X(t)M_Y(t)$. I know where is the problem now. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add little to [Jethro](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/516814/jethro)'s answer (which I do not understand exactly why was downvoted), but I want to put some order to the discussion in comments.

From the hypothesis we can conclude the following.

1. Taking $\beta = 0$ and $\beta = \frac{\pi}2$ leads to $X\sim N(0,1)$, and $Y\sim N(0,1)$, respectively.
2. For any $a,b\in \Bbb R$, $aX+bY \sim N(0,a^2+b^2)$. In fact we have $$aX+
   bY=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}(X\cos\beta + Y\sin \beta)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}Z,$$where $$\beta=\arctan \left(\frac ba\right).$$Therefore $(X,Y)$ have a [bivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution).
3. In particular $W=X+Y\sim N(0,2)$, implying $\mbox{E}\left[W^2\right]=2$. Hence the result, already shown, that $$\mbox{Cov}(X,Y)=\mbox{E}[XY]=\frac12\mbox{E}\left[W^2-X^2-Y^2\right]=0.$$Thus $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.
4. Uncorrelation and 2. guarantee independence. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Should it be that $\beta = \arctan(b/a)$? It looks like using $a/b$ instead gives $aY + bX$ but I'm unsure.

Comment: Correct, I'll amend it. Thanks @Slade

Comment: Or $\beta=\operatorname{atan2}(b,\,a)$, if you want to be a stickler.

Comment: @J.G. yes, definitely that is even better...

Answer (score 1):

We just need to show that $\text{Cov} (X,Y)=0$. To do this, note that when $\beta = \pi/4$, we have $\frac 1{\sqrt 2} (X+Y)\sim N(0,1)$, so $E[(X+Y)^2/2]=1, E(X+Y)^2=2$.

$$
\text{Cov} (X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)\\
=\frac12 E[(X+Y)^2-X^2-Y^2]-0\times 0\\
=\frac{1}{2}\times (2-1-1)=0.
$$
So, they are independent.

Note I have used the fact that $E(X)=E(Y)=0, E(X^2)=E(Y^2)=1$.

Comment: Your way of calculating $E(XY)$ inspires me. However, based on my knowledge, **$Cov(X,Y)=0$ cannot conclude $X,Y$ are independent.**

Comment: @christ : It is true that this answer falls somewhat short of proving independence, but perhaps not as far short as you seem to suggest. There is a theorem stating that if the pair $(X,Y)$ is so distributed that for every pair $(a,b)$ of constants $\text{(“constant''} = \text{not random})$ the linear combination $aX+bY$ is normally distributed, then $X,Y$ are independent if their covariance is $0. \qquad$